# Accord du verbe quand sujet ambigu

Tags: accord, pluriel, noms-propres

Je souhaite exprimer le fait que les membres d'un groupe de musique se sont séparés, mais le nom du groupe est au singulier (ici "Le Vautour"). Dois-je écrire:

> Le Vautour s'est séparé.

ou:

> Le Vautour se sont séparés.

Je tiens à garder "Le Vautour" comme sujet.
Par ailleurs il s'agit d'une séparation physique, le groupe étant toujours formé mais les membres rentrant chez eux par des routes différentes. L'ambigüité avec la fin du groupe est voulue, aussi je souhaite garder le verbe "se séparer".

Comment: Aucun des deux si tu ne souhaites pas aliéner le lecteur (gramaticalement). Si ce n'est pas un titre « le groupe » devrait suffire, non?

Comment: Comme la question le précise, je tiens à garder "le Vautour" comme sujet, j'ai aussi une problématique de concision qui est pour moi dans ce cas précis prioritaire par rapport à la santé grammaticale du lecteur.

Comment: Je te conseille : "**Les Vautour se sont séparés**", de même que l'on dit "**Les Clash obtiennent leur premier titre à succès**", avec Clash faisant référence au groupe "The Clash" où on omet donc l'article définit et conserve le singulier (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Clash).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il n'y a pas de solution avec les contraintes imposées.

Si on garde *"Le Vautour"* comme sujet. On se sépare de quelque chose, ici ce sont **les membres du groupe qui se séparent**, pas le groupe lui-même. Le groupe éclate, se disperse, se dissous, comme écrit par jlliagre.
Se séparer est un verbe **transitif indirect**, il y a nécessairement un complément qui le suit et c'est pour ça que tes phrases sont fausses. Toutes les constructions que je suis parvenu à faire sont au mieux maladroites, au pire incorrectes.

Si on garde les deux, il n'y a aucun choix possible, il ne sont ni grammaticalement ni sémantiquement correct. Ce qui est assez important, même pour un exercice de synthèse.
Il faut soit changer le verbe, soit changer le sujet :

### **Changer de sujet :**

> "Les Vautour(s) se sont séparés."

Celle-ci est je pense au plus proche de ce que tu souhaites : On personnifie l'étiquette *"Le Vautour"* pour désigner ses membres, c'est très courant en français (*"les U2"* désigne les musiciens et non le groupe en soi)
On peut choisir ici d'accorder Vautour au pluriel

> "Les membres se sont séparés."
> "Les membres des Vautours se sont
> séparés."

### **Changer de verbe :**

> "Le Vautour s'est dispersé."
> "Le Vautour s'est éparpillé."
>
> "Le Vautour s'est désolidarisé."(Le sens est un peu éloigné, il faut voir en fonction du contexte)
>
> "Le Vautour s'est disséminé." (Sens assez éloigné aussi, cf Contexte et les effets que l'on souhaite faire passer)

Comment: Certes, ce sont les membres qui se séparent, mais est-il pour autant incorrect d'utiliser le nom du groupe pour désigner l'ensemble des personnes le constituant ?

Comment: C'est possible et c'est justement le sens de la phrase "Les Vautour(s) se sont séparés.". Le détail qui change tout est le mot *"Les"*. Il montre bien qu'on parle des membres du groupe, et non du groupe en lui-même. C'est une pratique très courante en français : *"Les Daft Punk(s)"* désignent les musiciens du groupe et non le groupe. *"Les IUT informatique"* désignent les étudiants en IUT informatique, et non l'Institut Universitaire en lui-même.

Comment: Cette réponse est fausse. On peut tout à fait dire que le groupe se sépare. Les phrases proposées sont correctes, mais « Le Vautour s'est séparé » est aussi correct.

Answer (score 2):

Le verbe *se séparer* peut prendre comme sujet aussi bien l'objet qui est coupé en morceaux que les morceaux. Voir le [*Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/s%C3%A9parer), 2<sup>e</sup> Section (emploi pronominal) I.A. qui donne entre autres citations :

> [La cire] est tenace et cassante; elle se sépare en morceaux lorsqu'on la frappe (Kapeler, Caventou)
>   Les éléments du liquide que rencontre l'avant du corps se séparent pour glisser sur le solide de part et d'autre (Painlevé)

Il est donc tout à fait normal de dire et d'écrire

> Le groupe *Le Vautour* s'est séparé.

ou

> Le Vautour s'est séparé.

Le pluriel est grammaticalement correct lorsque le sujet contient un élément pluriel qui qualifie un nom singulier (l'ensemble des …, la plupart des …, etc.) mais en l'absence de pluriel visible, mettre le verbe au pluriel serait, sinon incorrect, à tout le moins incongru.

Comment: Par curiosité (je n'en ai pas besoin pour ce cas précis mais ça m'intéresse), si au lieu d' *un* groupe on avait *une* organisation, dirait-on "Le Vautour s'est *séparée* "?

Comment: @AnneAunyme Hmm, « Le groupe *La Chouette* s'est séparé », « La Chouette s'est … » J'ai tendance à écrire « séparée » mais je pense que les deux sont possibles. Et si le nom du groupe était au pluriel j'aurais tendance à mettre le verbe au pluriel.

Answer (score 0):

Une formule simple pourrait être:

> Le Vautour, c'est terminé ! (c.f. [Le Monde](http://www.lemonde.fr/culture/article/2010/11/30/noir-desir-c-est-termine_1447039_3246.html))

Si « Le Vautour » doit rester le sujet direct, suivant la violence de la séparation, on pourrait écrire :

> Le Vautour éclate.

ou

> Le Vautour se dissout. (c.f. [france-info](http://www.francetvinfo.fr/culture/musique/le-groupe-noir-desir-se-dissout_1624449.html))

S'il faut garder « séparer » :

> Le Vautour, séparation !

ou

> Le Vautour s'est séparé.

et si l'on souhaite que la phrase soit compréhensible pour les personnes ne connaissant pas ce groupe :

> Le groupe Le Vautour s'est séparé. (c.f. Le groupe Téléphone s'est séparé)

exactement comme on peut dire:

> Le couple s'est séparé.

En revanche « <s>Le Vautour se sont séparés</s> » et « <s>le couple se sont séparés</s> » sont impossibles car un sujet unique au singulier est incompatible avec un verbe au pluriel.

Answer (score 0):

Pourquoi pas un marquage typographique ?

- "Le Vautour" se sont séparés.
- *Le Vautour* se sont séparés.